# Remove Nvidia Drivers

Tags: graphic-drivers, drivers, graphics, nvidia, intel

I would like to remove COMPLETLY the nvidia drivers, and only use the intel GPU. How can i do that?
I tried `sudo apt remove nvidia-*` and installed `xserver-xorg-video-intel`. But it all came to the same conclusion: the nvidia GPU was still being used. 
PC:

```
-i7 6700QH
-gtx1060
-8gb DDR4
-MSI GP62MVR-6RF
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remove them by using:

`sudo apt-get autoremove nvidia*`

It will remove everything related to nvidia, so make sure to double check before continuing.

You can also try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I'm not sure if removing nvidia drivers will stop your nvidia GPU. It will probably still work and use Nouveau drivers, but I'm not sure.

Have you tried `sudo prime-select intel` with your nvidia drivers installed?

Comment: That last command, what does it do? I know very little of drivers, nouveu and stuff relsted to thst... I just followed awnser from others forums.
I even tried bumblebee, but everytime I checked the nvidia-settings, It never had the option to switch from GPU, did not even recognize the GPU thst i had! 
I'll try the last command and post here the output.

Comment: It should switch to intel, but on my PC, only nvidia is available, but that's probably because my HDMI cable is plugged directly in my nvidia GPU. Why do you actually want to use the intel GPU?

Comment: Because i use a laptop, and i the work I do on it (programming) dont require the power from nvidia, which takes a lot of energy. I basicly want to increase power effiency. (Sorry for the bad English)

Comment: Have you already solved your problem? I don't think I can help you anymore.

Comment: It says "command prime-select not found"

Comment: Take a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/661922/how-am-i-supposed-to-use-nvidia-prime

Comment: It worked! I basicly purged all nvidia related stuff, reinstalled, installed prime and suddently the option to change GPU appeared. Its officialy working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it's working. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the latest official driver from Nvidia, there is an option to switch to 'Power save mode' which uses the Intel GPU and you do not need to remove the driver.

[image]

Comment: the Intel Powersave mode doesn't improve battery life a lot on my Dell laptop. I still have a discharge rate of 17w while on Manjaro I have a discharge rate of 6-7w which will improve my battery life from 4 hours to 11 hours